# How to save the image to SD card on button Click android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I am using an Imageview and a Button in 1 XML, and I am retriving the images as URL from webServer and displaying it on the ImageView. Now if the Button(Save) is clicked I need to save that particular image into SD card. How to do this?

NOTE: Present Image Should be saved.

Comment: There are a lot of answers to your question, use search first!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4875114/android-save-image-from-url-onto-sd-card

Answer (score 52, accepted):

First, you need to get your Bitmap. You can already have it as an object Bitmap, or you can try to get it from the ImageView such as:

```
    BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) mImageView1.getDrawable();
    Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();
```

Then you must get to directory (a [File](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html) object) from SD Card such as:

```
    File sdCardDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

Next, create your specific file for image storage:

```
    File image = new File(sdCardDirectory, "test.png");
```

After that, you just have to write the Bitmap thanks to its method [compress](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#compress%28android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat,%20int,%20java.io.OutputStream%29) such as:

```
    boolean success = false;

    // Encode the file as a PNG image.
    FileOutputStream outStream;
    try {

        outStream = new FileOutputStream(image);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream); 
        /* 100 to keep full quality of the image */

        outStream.flush();
        outStream.close();
        success = true;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Finally, just deal with the boolean result if needed. Such as:

```
    if (success) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image saved with success",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Error during image saving", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Don't forget to add the following permission in your Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: R u Sure,This example saves the present image on buttonclick.I tried but its not getting saved

Comment: Rectified.Very Very Clear Example..Works Great,Thanks dude

Comment: @ Romain: How to save the images in diferent names.If i clicks to save other image previous image got overrided..Whether we need to calculate the count of images stored there to do so

Comment: Yes. For example you can use a static field in your class to increment the number of saved images. After, you can use it to generate the name of file. Or else you can use a timestamp in the name of file. Using [System.currentTimeMillis()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis%28%29) for example.

Comment: @RomainR. can you tell me how to do this when using camera

Comment: According to the following tutorial: https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html, we can see that the `onActivityResult` provides us a `Bitmap` as an extra.

Answer (score 5):

Probable Solution is

[Android - Saving a downloaded image from URL onto SD card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5886965/android-how-to-save-a-downloaded-image-form-url-into-sd-card#)

```
Bitmap bitMapImg;
void saveImage() {
        File filename;
        try {
            String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();

            new File(path + "/folder/subfolder").mkdirs();
            filename = new File(path + "/folder/subfolder/image.jpg");

            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filename);

            bitMapImg.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();

            MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), filename.getAbsolutePath(), filename.getName(), filename.getName());

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File is Saved in  " + filename, 1000).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```