# How to display an image from my SQLite database in a button

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a `SQLite` database that contains a table `image` : 
this table contains

- The `image` id
- The `url` of an `image`

  ```
  private static final String CREATE_BD_IMAGE="CREATE TABLE " 
      + TABLE_IMAGE + " (" +
      COL_ID_IMAGE + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
      COL_ADRESS_IMAGE + " TEXT NOT NULL ); " ;
  ```

I want to know how can I display this `image` on the `button`.

Comment: you can use android query to load images. https://code.google.com/p/android-query/#Image_Loading

Comment: How can i put it on button !!

Comment: here's a method that i created :
public String getImage(int i)//afficher une image 
    {
     String res;
     Cursor c = database.rawQuery("SELECT " + COL_ADRESS_IMAGE + "FROM " + TABLE_IMAGE + "WHERE id_image IN (SELECT " + COL_IMAGE_CATEGORY +
       "FROM " + TABLE_CATEGORY + "WHERE " + COL_ID_CATEGORY + "= '" +i +"')",null );
     res=c.toString();
     return res;
    }

Comment: use ImageButton : aq.id(imageButton).image(url, true, true, 100, R.drawable.default_thumbnail);

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you

```
 ImageView view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                        String uriString = c.getString(c
                                        .getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_URI));
                        view.setImageURI(Uri.parse(uriString));
```

Comment: I write this into my method or what !!

Comment: here c is curser
      `Cursor c = dm.query(query);`
so     `c.getColumnIndex` must have a uri of that image.

Comment: I haven't an imageview1 in my file .xml
and isn't too clear :(

Comment: Please can you explain me better

Comment: public String getImage(int id)//afficher une image
    {
     database = DBHelper.getReadableDatabase();
     Cursor c = database.rawQuery("SELECT " + COL_ADRESS_IMAGE + "FROM "+ TABLE_IMAGE + "WHERE id_image IN (SELECT " + COL_IMAGE_CATEGORY + "FROM " + TABLE_CATEGORY + "WHERE " + COL_ID_CATEGORY + "= '" + id +"')",null );
     if(c.moveToFirst())
     { String strCatName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COL_ADRESS_IMAGE ));
           c.close();
           database.close();
            return strCatName;
          }
     else 
     {c.close();
        database.close();
      return "";}
    }

Comment: See here is step by step process for it
`1. get image uri from sqlite db`
`2. use cursor for query so that the cursor will hold the URI of Image`
`3. Use ImageButton and then after set ImageUri to that Button.
let me know if need code snippet`

Comment: Thanks a lot for this informations, what i wrote it in the previous commentaire isn't correct !! 
If it's false tell me what can i do for correct it

Comment: I just want to know the uri of image is String type??

Comment: How can i stored an image in sdcard of mobile ??

Comment: sorry for late reply
to store images in sd card please check this answer :-
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9396243/how-to-save-the-image-to-sd-card-on-button-click-android

Answer (score 0):

the [Volley library](https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/325304728) (made by google) has a very intuitive class for an imageView that can have a url , called "NetworkImageView" .

if you load many images urls, you should read more about this library since it could be very handy for you.

you should check it out.

for setting the url, just use setImageUrl .

it has some useful methods for the phases of loading too: setDefaultImageResId , setErrorImageResId.

Comment: Can Volley use a local sql database?

Comment: @SoroushA I still don't use Volley :)