# coverting a imageview to bitmap and save thT

Tags: android, image, bitmap, imageview, save

I developing kind of image editor and I having a problem with saving final image to the mobile. I'd tried code below for saving the final image.but i have a problem.this is my problem:
1-i save the imageview
2-after that i edit the image view (add some effects or  changing background)
i wanna save the new image but when i use save button my app save the first image .
*i changed the image several time but my app save the first image 
plz help me

```
  save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        img1.buildDrawingCache();
        Bitmap bp = img1.getDrawingCache();

        String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
            File newDir = new File(root + "/insta/pics");    
            newDir.mkdirs();
            Random gen = new Random();
             int n = 10000;
            n = gen.nextInt(n);
            String fotoname = "instaPhoto-"+n+".jpg";
           File file = new File (newDir, fotoname);
            if (file.exists ()) file.delete (); 
                try {
                    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    bp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
                   out.flush();
                   out.close();
                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " /insta/pics  ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();

                } catch (Exception e) {

                }

         }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer that show exactly how to save an imageVIew to SD card. [How to save the image to SD card on button Click android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9396243/how-to-save-the-image-to-sd-card-on-button-click-android)