# How to save a picture in an application?

Tags: java, android, image, save

I want to know how I can save an image in my storage because in my app I can take a photo and see it, but when I close my app and reopen it, the image disappears I have used bitmap.

**My code:**

```java
public static final int REQUEST_CODE = 01;
private ImageView imgs1;
private File outputMediaFile;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.semana1);
     imgs1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgs1);
}

public void btnTakePhotoClicked1(View v){
    Intent intent1= new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(intent1, REQUEST_CODE);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        Bitmap bm1= (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        imgs1.setImageBitmap(bm1);
    }
}
```

Comment: You wanna save them in gallery or in app only?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9396243/how-to-save-the-image-to-sd-card-on-button-click-android check it

Comment: I only want that the image don't disappear.

Comment: @spain Please do not deface your own question.

Comment: save that bitmap path in SharedPreference and when open app again check it and load again using that path

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in onActivityResult, after you have obtained the image bitmap object.

```
File file = new File("foldername/imagename.jpg")
OutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
bm1.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, fOut);
fOut.flush();
fOut.close();
```