# Storing data with key / value

Tags: java, android, store

I have this app , it consists of two activities:

1. activity 1 : inserts data.
2. activity 2 : show inserted data.

Now on activity 1 I want to store data with key \ value that can be stored in a single file .

For example:
 one file would store three strings and one image.

I've tried using sharedPreferences but it does not store images
also when I encode the image to Base64 and then put in the sharedPreferences.
then the stored sharedPref.xml size becomes over 150K and my image is only 5K

So what I want to do is store values with image in one single file and then transfer those files to be displayed in the second activity.

How can I do this?

Comment: Save the image files in the internal storage. And in your key/value storage, let the value be the path of the saved image.

Comment: Take a look at [Content Providers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html) - it gives you the ability to do just that.  It involves a little bit more work but is scalable.

Answer (score 0):

dont need to store image at sharedpreference( actually its not possible) .. just you need to save image path only as a value and save the image in sd card or phone memory  . and load the image again at second activity from sd card and get the image path from sharedpreference.

[save image on sd card](https://looksok.wordpress.com/2013/07/13/android-tutorial-save-bitmap-image-on-android-sd-card/)

[how to save the image to sd card on button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9396243/how-to-save-the-image-to-sd-card-on-button-click-android)