# how i can save itext image to image file (jpg)?

Tags: android, itext

Is there a way to save the com.itextpdf.text.Image file as a jpg file on the SD card in android?

I am creating an image from template and i want the image to be saved on the SD card. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9396243/how-to-save-the-image-to-sd-card-on-button-click-android

Comment: iText doesn't render PDF pages to images. The `Image` object you obtained from a `PdfImportedPage` is a vector image consisting of PDF syntax that can only be reused in another PDF. You can change it into a raster image such as jpg.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to save the image to SD card on button Click android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9396243/how-to-save-the-image-to-sd-card-on-button-click-android)

Comment: @BrunoLowagie  Is this possible yet?