# My download video code does not works in android 4.0

Tags: android

I have done video file download code for the application and its working perfact for the version upto 2.3.3 but it does not working properly  in the android 4.0 and it is giving the error like  java.io.FileNotFoundException
Can anyone help me to solve this problem?
Thanks in advance

```
public void video_download(String urlstring, String Name) {

    URL url;
    try {
        url = new URL(urlstring);
        HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        c.setRequestMethod("GET");
        c.setDoOutput(true);
        c.connect();

        String PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + "/application/";
        Log.v("PATH", "PATH: " + PATH);
        File file = new File(PATH);
        file.mkdirs();
        String fileName;
        fileName = Name + ".mp4";

        File outputFile = new File(file, fileName);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

        InputStream is = c.getInputStream();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int len1 = 0;
        while ((len1 = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            fos.write(buffer, 0, len1);
        }
        fos.close();
        is.close();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure it's not throwing NetworkOnMainThreadException?

Comment: ya i m sure.Now i got the solution i changes the code from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9406265/url-file-not-found-exception/9406341#9406341 and its working fine for me now

Comment: okey Good, Dear. you can also past your answer here. and accept it your self so may help another developer also..