# Android - Save Bitmap Image on Mobile Storage without Compressing

Tags: java, android, image, bitmap

The typical way (based on research) for saving bitmap images from a remote url is:

```
Bitmap bmImage = null;

InputStream in = new java.net.URL(imageUrl).openStream();
bmImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);

File file = new File(myPath);

FileOutputStream outputStream;
outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);

bmImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outputStream);

outputStream.close();
```

I cannot save bitmap unless it is compressed (Bitmap is always uncompressed).
The remote image size is 32KB, after compression it gets 110KB.
I know I have to lower compression parameter to get smaller size, but the remote image is optimize and much more efficient.

Is there a way I can save the remote image on mobile storage without compressing it?

===== **ANSWER TO MY PROBLEM** =====

First I apologize for misleading content; all I wanted is to save images that could be png|jpeg|gif|etc.. Probably I mislead you guys that the image I am trying to save is in BMP format, but it is not.

Nevertheless, for those who want to save images WITHOUT compressing, have a look to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9411276/1271263)

Answer (score 1):

Use [AndroidBmpUtil](https://github.com/ultrakain/AndroidBitmapUtil/blob/master/src/com/ultrasonic/android/image/bitmap/util/AndroidBmpUtil.java) as shown in the code below:

```java
new AndroidBmpUtil().save(bmImage, file);
```

Comment: That makes the image size even bigger; 232KB  :(

Comment: How to use this class ?

Comment: java.nio.BufferOverflowException crash in that class