# Save image in original form and without compressing

Tags: android, image, android-camera, android-bitmap

I want to save the image without compressing it and want to save it in it's original form i.e. when image is compressed the image size decreases and image become small. I am using native camera for this purpose. I am working in `android studio`. I am making an app in which i am using a camera to save image. But the image is compressed and is very small and very lower quality.

Below is my code for saving image

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    final LocationSettingsStates states = LocationSettingsStates.fromIntent(data);
    if(requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE)
    {
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
        {
            Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data");
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
            byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

            // convert byte array to Bitmap
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);

            if(isStoragePermissionGranted())
            {
                SaveImage(bitmap);
            }


        }
    }else {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 1000:
                switch (resultCode) {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        // All required changes were successfully made
                        getLocation();
                        break;
                    case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                        // The user was asked to change settings, but chose not to
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Location Service not Enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                break;
        }

    }


}

private void SaveImage(Bitmap finalBitmap) {

    File storageDir = new File (String.valueOf(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)));
    String root = storageDir + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath().toString();
    Log.v(LOG_TAG, root);
    File myDir = new File(root + "/captured_images");
    if (!myDir .exists())
    {
        myDir .mkdirs();
    }
    Random generator = new Random();
    int n = 1000;
    n = generator.nextInt(n);
    String fname = "Image-" + n + ".jpg";
    File file = new File(myDir,fname);
    try {
        file.createNewFile();
        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(getApplicationContext(), new String[]  {file.getPath()} , new String[]{"image/*"}, null);
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

**Update 1**

For more understanding i am putting my `onClick` method

```
   btn_camera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Check permission for camera

            if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, CAMERA)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            {
                // Check Permissions Now
                // Callback onRequestPermissionsResult interceptado na Activity MainActivity

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                        new String[]{CAMERA},
                        MainActivity.REQUEST_CAMERA);
            }
            else {


                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE );

            }


        }
    });
```

I searched the solution and found that i can use [AndroidBitmapUtil](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32940449/6854117)
 class so i copy and pasted this [class](https://github.com/ultrakain/AndroidBitmapUtil/blob/master/src/com/ultrasonic/android/image/bitmap/util/AndroidBmpUtil.java) into my project i.e. i created a new class. But i don't know how to use it. Although it is described that i can save image by doing `new AndroidBmpUtil().save(bmImage, file);`. But again i can't match with my code :(

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: The camera app saved a big file to .../DCIM/Camera. But you are using and saving a thumbnail of the image. Hence the low quality. You should provide a path to your camera intent where the camera app will save the image. Basic stuff. You are number #### who asks this.

Comment: @greenapps kindly see my updated code

Answer (score 2):

new AndroidBmpUtil().save(source, sdcardBmpPath);

USER ABOVE LINE OF CODE AND FOLLOW BELOW LINK

https://github.com/ultrakain/AndroidBitmapUtil

Comment: I have figured out some thing and set up the code as per my understanding but when i run the app it doesn't run and gives me error 
`Error:(39, 30) error: cannot find symbol method getWidth()` , `Error:(40, 31) error: cannot find symbol method getHeight()` , `Error:(62, 18) error: cannot find symbol method getPixels(int[],int,int,int,int,int,int)`

These all are in `AndroidBmpUtil` 

If you know how to solve this issue kindly tell me. I'll try to implement the other method given by you if this one not resolve my issue

Comment: Works like a breeze

Answer (score 1):

Open Camera and save image into some specific directory.

solution number 1

```
private String pictureImagePath = "";

private void openBackCamera() {

String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());

String imageFileName = timeStamp + ".jpg";

File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
        Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);

pictureImagePath = storageDir.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + imageFileName;

File file = new File(pictureImagePath);

Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);

Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);               

cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);

startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 1);}
```

Handle Image

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

if (requestCode == 1) {
File imgFile = new  File(pictureImagePath);

    if(imgFile.exists()){        

   Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());

   ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageviewTest);

   myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

    }
}
```

solution number 2

I have used the following code and this works perfectly fine for me.

```
        values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, "New Picture");

        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "From your Camera");

        imageUri = getContentResolver().insert(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);

        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);

        startActivityForResult(intent, PICTURE_RESULT);
```

and also

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    switch (requestCode) {

    case PICTURE_RESULT:

        if (requestCode == PICTURE_RESULT)

            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

                try {

                    thumbnail = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(

                            getContentResolver(), imageUri);

                    imgView.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);

                    imageurl = getRealPathFromURI(imageUri);    

                } catch (Exception e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();

                }

            }
    }
}
```

and

```
public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {

    String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);

    int column_index = cursor

            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);

    cursor.moveToFirst();

    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```

Comment: Values is in string type ?

Comment: and i will be using it in `onCreate` method.?

Comment: inside onclick method

Comment: yes dear friend..please accept my answer and increase my reputations :-)

Comment: When i am doing `values = new ContentValues()` it's giving me error incompatible types. and  my declaration is `String values, imageUri`

Comment: replace - ContentValues values;  and String imageUri;

Comment: Also facing same error in `imageUri` so i have declared them `ContentValues values;
    Uri imageUri;`

Comment: Also i am not using `imageView` so should i skip this piece of code ? ` thumbnail = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(

                            getContentResolver(), imageUri);

                    imgView.setImageBitmap(thumbnail)`

Comment: I am getting this error while saving the image ` java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1888, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.example.accurat.application/com.example.accurat.application.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'byte[] android.content.Intent.getByteArrayExtra(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                                                   `

Answer (score 1):

For opening camera use

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
 File f = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "imagename.jpg");
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

and in your onActivityresult method use

```
if (requestCode == 1) {
 File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString());
  for (File temp : f.listFiles()) {
   if (temp.getName().equals("imagename.jpg")) {
    f = temp;
     break;
  }
  }
  try {
   Bitmap bitmap;
   BitmapFactory.Options bitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();

       bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath(),bitmapOptions);

      yourimageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

  } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
```

Comment: I am able to open the camera in my `onClick` method i have `  Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE );`

Comment: ya that is alright...but i am passing file uri also while opening the camera. ie.. the location to save the image .so i guess it will get saved without any compression

Comment: i am not using image view so where to pass `bitmap` ?

Comment: it is not compalsary to use imageview. you can use that piece of code   in onActivityResult method to get image in anywhere in your application to get the image in bitmap format.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136852/discussion-between-faisal1208-and-ramees).

Comment: the link provided in chat doesn't help me out